# How to use use web identify token in aws to authenticate using go sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-eks, aws-sdk-go

I am trying to write an example of how to use a web identity token with a container to perform EC2 operations.
The container spec contains the service account and has the necessary permission to access the token path and its namespace is a trusted entity in the role.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/credentials"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/credentials/stscreds"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/ec2"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/sts"
)

func main() {

    sess, _ := session.NewSession()
    config := aws.NewConfig().WithRegion("us-east-1")

    stsSTS := sts.New(sess)
    roleARN := "arn:aws:iam::1234567:role/s2-p0o5-csi-drivers-ebs-cloud-credentials"

    roleProvider := stscreds.NewWebIdentityRoleProviderWithOptions(stsSTS, roleARN, "gosession", stscreds.FetchTokenPath("/build/token"))

    creds := credentials.NewCredentials(roleProvider)
    credValue, _ := roleProvider.Retrieve()
    fmt.Printf("credValue.AccessKeyID: %v\n", credValue.AccessKeyID)
    fmt.Printf("credValue.SecretAccessKey: %v\n", credValue.SecretAccessKey)
    fmt.Printf("credValue.SessionToken: %v\n", credValue.SessionToken)

    config = config.WithCredentials(creds)

    nodeID := "i-00843f27cfeb0beff"
    svc := ec2.New(sess, config)
    request := &ec2.DescribeInstancesInput{
        InstanceIds: []*string{&nodeID},
    }

    result, _ := svc.DescribeInstances(request)
    fmt.Printf("result: %v\n", result)
}
```

The value of result get empty. Whereas, i have exported (credValue.AccessKeyID, credValue.SecretAccessKey,credValue.SessionToken) as environment variables and aws cli is giving me output related to describing the instance.

I tried various methods like `credentials.NewStaticCredentials()` with the credential information, but no luck. Can some help share hint on what is going wrong and correct way of doing it.

Comment: The error returned from DescribeInstances may describe the problem.  The error is ignored by the program in the question. Modify the program to assign the error to a variable and print that variable.

Comment: I did that, unfortunately it gives `nil`.
```
sh-4.4# go run main.go
result: {

}
err: <nil>
```

Comment: Thank you Bellingham Boss, your hint helped. Seems the err is nil even if the instance does not exist, strange.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation on this is very poor. There is 1 sentence in [pod configuration guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/pod-configuration.html) about using the supported AWS SDK versions (the environment variables mentioned are the ones injected by the webhook as a result of pod having the service account configured):

> The supported versions of the AWS SDK look for these environment variables first in the credential chain provider.

Then on the page that lists the [supported SDK versions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/iam-roles-for-service-accounts-minimum-sdk.html):

> When using IAM roles for service accounts, the containers in your pods must use an AWS SDK version that supports assuming an IAM role through an OpenID Connect web identity token file.

This suggests that SDK is able to detect the env variables, which I found out to be the case after going through the relevant modules in SDK code (note I am using the aws-go-v2):

- [config/env_config.go](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/blob/main/config/env_config.go#L47)
- [config/resolve_credentials.go](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/blob/main/config/resolve_credentials.go#L94)

which lead me to the following:

```
import (
  "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config"
  "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/ec2"
)

cfg, _ := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.Background(), config.WithRegion("us-west-1))

client := ec2.NewFromConfig(&cfg)
```

Use `client` to get whatever data you need - token from file will be used to assume the role and temporary role credentials will be used for the request.

Answer (score 0):

The instance-id used should be avaiable in the region, else it returns an empty map with err == nil.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).